# PHP changing html element class from SQL variable

Tags: php

### Background

- Here is the following code which will select four fields from a MySQL table
  called `a_aif`
- I want to present this data in an html table and **highlight** the row background where the `a_aif.aif_id` is equal to `remaining_if.aif_id`
- I have defined a variable in the SQL query that satisfies this condition above and defined it `remaining_aifs`

**Issues** - Please see the red arrows/highlighted syntax for where I think the problem lies...

[image]

### PHP Script

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$result = $dbh->query("
    SELECT a_aif.aif_id,
      a_aif.fee_source_id,
      a_aif.company_name_per_sedar,
      a_aif.document_filing_date,
      IF (a_aif_remaining.aif_id IS NULL, 0, 1) remaining_aifs
    FROM  a_aif
      LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining
        ON a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
    ORDER BY aif_id DESC");

$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ( !empty($result) ) : endif;

?>

<table>
<tr>
    <th><b>Document ID</b></th>
    <th><b>Pubco Name</b></th>
    <th><b>Filing Date</b></th>
    <th><b>PDF</b></th>
</tr>

<?php foreach($result as $index => $row) : ?>
<tr
    <?php
        if('a_aif.aif_id' === 'remaining_aifs'
        echo "<tr class='highlighted'>";
        else echo "<tr>";
    ?>
>
    <td><?php echo $row[fee_source_id]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[company_name_per_sedar]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[document_filing_date]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;
$dbh = NULL;
?>
</table>
```

Comment: That's not correct. It's not even valid PHP syntax.

Comment: No. Are you even trying to run this yourself to see what happens? For starters, you're missing the `?` in `<?php` and your code results in a parse error when run.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this? Describe that and it might be easier to help you.

Comment: OK. I will update this question with context.

Comment: @regulatethis I've updated the question to include the context. Appreciate your help, been at this one for a while... little confusing for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22102/discussion-between-ben-jones-and-regulatethis)

Comment: I don't understand the point of this line: `if ( !empty($result) ) : endif;` If you're not doing anything in the if statement, why bother putting it there at all? Your code has a few errors in it just at a glance.

Comment: @regulatethis my code is not working, but I think there are a few errors, like you point out. (1) I am not making any use of the PDO fetch? (2) like you say, the if statement may be a waste and not be achieving anything - what I am trying to accomplish is the standard/safe practice of always saying "if the result is empty, do nothing. where are the errors you notice? can you help me fix it up and teach me where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1) `empty()` is a construct which returns true if the value you pass it is any of the following:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

2) `$result` is some value that is being passed in to `empty()`. No idea what it is set to since you didn't post any other code.

3) The `:` is an alternative syntax to define a block for the if statement. You'll need to end it with `endif;` at the end of your block.

This alternative syntax is very popular when using PHP mixed with HTML, typically in a template. Your code might look like this:

```
<?php if ( !empty($result) ) : ?>
   <span class="result"><?php echo $result; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note that what you put between the `<?php if...` and `<?php endif; ?>` lines can be anything, including more php code or html/text.

More info:

http://www.php.net/empty

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Thanks @regulatethis. Can you please expand on number 3? Do I still need to add `endif;` to this code block (assuming no "else" portion to the If Statement)? - Please note, I have updated the question to reflect this deeper investigation. Thanks

Comment: @BenJones You should always close your if statements explicitly, if you want to write maintainable code.

Comment: `empty()` is not a function, but a language construct. At least with 5.5 this shouldn't make a huge difference anymore, but before the main difference to regular function is, that `empty()` only accepts variables (not `empty('')` or `empty(doSomething())`) Just said :)

Comment: @KingCrunch `empty()` supports expressions since PHP 5.5 so I didn't think mentioning that was particularly necessary or helpful.

Comment: @regulatethis 5.5 isn't released yet ;) So it's _obviously_ necessary to mention, that it wont work in regular installations and especially in every stable production environment

Answer (score 0):

this is alternate syntax of "if statement"

you can use

```
<?php 
if ($condition):
//some code
else:
// some code
endif;
?>
```

so in your example 1 and 2 are condition which is passed if result is not empty

Answer (score 0):

**An array looks like:**

```
$result= array(); // array defined

$result= ["name","last name"]; // array elements

$result= []; // empty array
```

**If Syntax :**

```
    <?php if ( !empty($result) ) : ?>
       hello control in if 
    <?php else: ?>
       in else condition
    <?php endif; ?>
```

where `empty();`  is a php function to check `$result` has no elements or have elements.

`:` is a syntax element.